# Where is Altium Designer 13 Supplier Unit Price in BOM?

Tags: altium

I got a month trial from Altium sometime in January, I believe that was Altium 12. While playing around with it, one thing we liked was that that for our BOM we can retrieve live supplier information such as unit price. I created a template, and everything looked good.

We recently upgraded to the latest Altium, and the Unit price in the supplier data is no longer there. Instead, there is a pricing column which has ALL prices for the varies quantities (1,10,50, 100 etc..). That's useless to me, because we want the total cost of the project within the BOM for our internal records.

Is this a bug or is there another way to extract a unit price ?

I'm still fairly new to learning the ins and outs of this software, I've only really played with it for about 2 weeks prior to this.

Comment: Upvoted to counter the drive-by downvote. This seems like a legitimate question that could be answered by this community.

Comment: This is not a bad question, but I think you'll get a better and more authoritative answer from Altium's support center or forum.